# Can we allow a user with Create Only permission (without Edit or Delete) to submit a list item and attach files

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, attachments, custom-permission-level

We have a scenario where we want to allow users to submit items but without been able to edit them or delete them. we only want admin users to be able to edit and delete the submitted items. so for this i created a new Permission Level, which is a copy of the built-in contribute permission, but i uncheck these 3 highlighted check-boxes:-

[image: User's image]

the issue i am facing is that users with this custom permission level can create a new list item, but they can not attach files to it, where the attachment control will be hidden, as follow. here is the create form for users with this custom permission level:-

[image: User's image]

unlike the admins which have an attachment control:-

[image: User's image]

any advice on this please? how we can allow users with this custom permission level to attach files?

Comment: I think adding attachment to list item is considered as edit/update operation because when you will click save button, first list item will be created and then attachment will be added to that particular list item (hence update operation). So, I think users will need edit items permissions to add attachments. Let me know if this clarifies your question.

Comment: @GaneshSanap ok i see .. so what do you think i can do on this case?

Comment: 1. You can grant edit items permissions to your users and then break item permissions on item creation using Power automate. 2. Create separate list for storing attachments (with lookup to main list & edit items permissions to user). 3. Use document library to upload the documents and use lookup column from your list to create relationship between list and library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior in SharePoint sites. Adding attachments to the list items is considered as edit/update operation because when you will click save button, SharePoint will first create a list item and then attachments will be added to that particular list item (hence update operation).

So, users will need edit items permissions to add attachments to the SharePoint list items.

**Possible workarounds?**:

1. You can grant edit items permissions on list to your users and then break item permissions on item creation using Power automate to grant read permissions to normal users & full control to admin users.
2. Create separate list for storing attachments (with lookup from your main list & edit items permissions to users).
3. Use document library to upload the documents and use lookup column from your list to create relationship between list and library.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Add an attachment to Sharepoint list in new item (permission level is without edit option)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/add-an-attachment-to-sharepoint-list-in-new-item/f8d3eb18-b7c6-40c6-955b-453e57fea91c)
2. [Permission level problem for attachment](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/permission-level-problem-for-attachment/m-p/202068)

Comment: the problem with the power automate flow, is that till the workflow runs (which might take 1-2 minutes)>> users can edit other users items. i am thinking of benefitting from the item-level setting inside the list. to define that users can only see and edit their own items, what do you think? and i can grant admin related permission to view all items (which can be done through a custom permission level which have checkout permission).. what do you think?

Comment: You can use OOTB item level permissions from list settings > advanced settings with **Create items and edit items that were created by the user**, but other users (including admins) cannot edit the items created by another users. You can try above once with granting admin related permissions using custom permission level as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're saying, this is a known issue from a long time ago, and there is no other way to allow users with this custom permission level to submit attachment files.

The only way to implement the option that the user can submit new items and upload attachments (without Edit or Delete) is through the Power Automate.

Reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/add-an-attachment-in-new-item-permission-level-is/61ed98b9-062e-4083-88c5-3cb2fce82c9d

As a possible workaround, you may use Power Automate to set users' permission on the added item to OnlyAddItem permission after they add the item automatically each time. So after that, they have no permission to edit the item and edit the attachment. However, they have permission to attach the files when they add a new item in the list. You can also create another flow for them to update the attachment files if they want to do that. They can submit a form to request to change the attachments and then the flow can send an email to them to let them upload the updated files to a new library.

[image]

Reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/add-an-attachment-to-sharepoint-list-in-new-item/f8d3eb18-b7c6-40c6-955b-453e57fea91c